# how do i setup a fallback plain text email in PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Is there an equivalent method to

```
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

for sending a plain text fallback email **with** the html email?

if that's how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$mail->AltBody` is what you want to set. Likewise you can use `$mail->Body` to set the html body of themessage. You only need to use `MsgHTML` if there are attachments and what not i believe.

Comment: I've realised that it was just gmail reads html without images by default,  i'll set it to send plain text to gmail / googlemail addresses. thanks for your help

Comment: Meanwhile, $mail->AltBody is optional. If not supplied, $mail->MsgHTML()  will automatically generate the alternative from the html message supplied.